# how to write this SQL query returns the number of users having the first name who have registered on each day.*

Tags: sql

An SQL table called `users` contains data about users. It has columns `id`, `firstname`, `lastname`, and `registerdate` (which has type DATE). Write a query that returns the number of users having the first name ‘Sally’ who have registered on each day.*

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    TRUNC(REGISTERDATE), COUNT(*) 
FROM 
    USERS 
WHERE 
    firstname = 'Sally' 
GROUP BY 
    TRUNC(REGISTERDATE)
```